# Where to store a C source file to link with every program

Tags: c, header-files, cs50

I'm currently enrolled in cs50 and they have their own library of functions tht we're supposed to use, so far i was writing code in only one folder called as `cs50` and i had both `cs50.h` and `cs50.c` files in the same folder and to include this library i was getting around with using `#include "cs50.h"` at the top and for compiling i used the following command, `gcc filename.c cs50.c` and it worked fine.
But now when i divided my codes in separate folders, its really cumbersome to copy both `cs50.h` and `cs50.c` to each and every subfolder to use them in my programs.
I copied the `cs50.h` to `C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include` folder and its being recognised in vscode, but when compiling it doesn't work. Can't seem to figure out where to put `cs50.c` file to use the command `-lcs50` for linking to every program.
Any workaround for this?
Thanks.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question concretely. We don't know if your 'multiple folders' contain source for multiple *targets* (e.g. programs and libs). If it does, then you need one additonal target that builds a cs50 library using the cs50.c source (static or dynamic is up to you), and a build-dependency system (make, cmake, etc.) that manages those dependencies. And note: if you find yourself 'fixing' *anything* by (a) copying headers into the  system header folders, or (b) replicating source code across multiple folders, you've already gone off the rails.

Comment: You need to build a `cs50.o` or `libcs50.a` link to that.  `-l` arguments do not look for `.c` files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to the compiler where to find the include files with -I and where to find the library with -L (gcc):

```
gcc -c your_program.c -I dirname_of_header_file
gcc your_program.o -o your_program -L dirname_of_library -lcs50
```

If you only have an object file, say. cs50.o, then you want to include it on the line when you link you program:

```
gcc cs50.o your_program.o -o your_progoram
```

You typically define this paths in your build system (Makefile). Tag your question with `vscode` if you need help with that.